# PlayerPrefs not being saved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written some PlayerPref code to show my high score on the screen. It works fine when I go into play mode the first time. But when I go into play mode for the second time, the high score doesn't have the "Best: " prefix anymore and is shown as a single number until I get a new high score, then the "Best: " prefix comes back. Here's my code:

```
void Start ()
{
    highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();
}

if (collision.tag == "Score")
    {
        scoreText.text = (++score).ToString();
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
            highScore.text = "Best: " + score.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just want this in the Start():

```
void Start ()
{
    highScore.text = "Best: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();
}
```

With your actual code, you necessarily have to beat the old score to have the "Best: " string appear.